# How to check input right in template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

Can I access the input value and check his value?
I want to disable the ability to change the key if it's equal to 'foo'.

```
.email-template-param-nested-fields
  - if :key == 'foo'
    = f.input :key, placeholder: 'foo', readonly: true
  - else
    = f.input :key, placeholder: 'key'
  = f.input :value, placeholder: 'example'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign variable as

```
- args = f.object.key == 'foo' ? { placeholder: 'foo', readonly: true } : { placeholder: 'key' }
```

And then

```
= f.input :key, **args
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do your conditional inline:

```
.email-template-param-nested-fields
  = f.input :key, placeholder: 'foo', readonly: (f.object.key == 'foo')
  = f.input :value, placeholder: 'example'
```